# Keep track of depth in the object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following piece of code as an example:

```
var someObject = {
    id:'a',
    l1:{
        id:'b',
        l2:null
    }
};

var pointer = someObject;
// seq = abc
function doSomething(seq) {
    while() {
        Step 1: seq.charAt(0) is a === l0.id, therefore pointer =  someObject.l1;
        Step 2: seq.charAt(1) is b === l1.id, therefore pointer =  pointer.l2;
        Step 3: seq.charAt(2) is c !== l2.id, therefore:
            pointer = { id: c, l3:null}
    }
}
```

After doSomething runs on `abc`, I want `someObject` to look like:

```
var someObject = {
    id:'a',
    l1:{
        id:'b',
        l2:{
            id:'c',
            l3:null
        }
    }
};
```

So the question is, how do I keep track of where in `someObject` I am, in the most efficient way? Or is it actually possible at all to keep track of the `pointer`?

Edit: In pure Javascript or even angular is fine. No jQuery please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK I figured it out. I completely missed this, but any recursion call will hold the "pointer." As an example, here is the answer to the code. I did have to modify the way the object was:

```
var someObject = {
    id:'a',
    l:{
        id:'b',
        l:{}
    }
};
```

And of course, just for the sake of this example, seq will always be adding on to whats already in the object. That is, if a>b>c, then seq will always match "abc" + anything extra, ex. "abcd"

```
function doSomething(seq, index, obj) {
    if(seq.charAt(index) === obj.id) {
        obj = obj.l;
        index++;
        doSomething(seq, index, obj)
    } else {
        obj.id = seq.charAt(index);
    }
}
```

As you can see, we are able to keep reference to the pointed original instead of a copy.

Output: `{ id: 'a', l: { id: 'b', l: { id: 'c' } } }`

If anyone thinks this is a bad way or there is a better way of doing it, please let me know :)